# Did anyone survive, or could anyone have survived the attack on the bus in "The Ghost Network"?

Tags: fringe

In *Fringe* S1E3, "The Ghost Network", we see an attack on a bus which leaves the people on it trapped in a substance not unlike what we later get to know as Amber 31422.

In S3E5, "Amber 31422", we learn that while people trapped in amber are officially pronounced dead, they actually aren't.

In S3E14, "6B", we see some of the victims of the attack on the bus, still trapped in amber.

So was the amber used in the attack actually Amber 31422, and could the victims have been saved, or was it just an amber-like substance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things here.

1. The bus amber was a prototype. Hence, the future version might have been life sustaining, but the prototype certainly wasn't.
2. The procedure to follow so as to recover someone after extraction from amber was not known at the time of the bus incident.

   So basically, in short,
   The amber may or may not have supported life sustenance, and even if it did, the procedure to recover a person was not known at the time.

Answer (score 0):

In "The Ghost Network," they were declared dead. Later on, the similarity between the Amber and the aerosol polymer used in the bus is commented on. However, the bus-Amber was a prototype for the delivery system, and did not have the properties of Amber i.e. life sustaining, wormhole stabilizing, etc. (Remember, Amber was originally designed by Walternate for use in the Alternate dimension, while in our world, we don't even see it until Season 5). In addition, the improper removal from Amber leads to death in the subjects, which the FBI certainly did, so the point is somewhat moot.